# PHP form is not sending user entered data

Tags: php, html, forms, email

**The PHP Code of send_form_email.php:**
http://pastebin.com/1W9vz7PP

**The HTML Code of the Form**
http://pastebin.com/MKL4HDHV

It is sending the email but it doesn't contain the user entered date so for example it emails

First name:

Surname:

Date of Birth:

Comment: What kind of error are you see printed? Why won't you post your code in your question?

Comment: try printing `$email_message` before calling `mail()`

Comment: @bcesars : Code is little bit huge. BTW, pastebin.com is used by many

Comment: Thought of Y2K problem but it is a "semicolon missing" problem :)

Comment: I removed the part as I said suspicious, I  really never seen this site before... I believe he doesn't need to paste the entire code. Only the important snippet which he needs help

Comment: @Aidan Hogg : BTW, why you didnt apply `clean_string()` to First Name and Sur Name ? Do you think is it safe ?

Comment: It reports no problem, the e-mail is sent but none of the user data is in it!

Answer (score 3):

You used

```
$email_message .= "First Name: ".($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Surname: ".($second_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Date of Birth: ".clean_string($dob)."\n";
```

Use $_POST for retrieve data

```
$email_message .= "First Name: ".($_POST['first_name'])."\n";
$email_message .= "Surname: ".($_POST['second_name'])."\n";
$email_message .= "Date of Birth: ".clean_string($_POST['dob'])."\n";
```

Same for rest of fields as well and it will work for you.

Comment: How I missed it ... :)

Comment: He posted whole code, seems very minor mistake :)

Comment: Hi,

Thanks but this is still not working!

Comment: You haven't get values so far?